# GBQ - How to automatically update table that was created from a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery, sql-update

I created a table from a query but that table does not automatically get updated when new data comes in. What can I do to create a table from a query and have this new created table update at a desired time frame?

For Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE project.dataset.mytable AS (
SELECT * FROM tableA
);
```

What changes can I make to make sure that this new table I created (mytable) is updated every day by running this query again?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a CRON Job?

Answer (score 1):

From the BQ UI you can schedule your query to run daily:
[image]